# Rings with fewer idempotent ideals generated by a single central idempotent.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

In a Noetherian ring $R$ every idempotent ideal is generated by a single idempotent element of $R$, that is, $I=Re$.   Suppose that, this time, the idempotent $e\in R$ is central and the idempotent ideal is $J=Re=eR$.  Is there an example of a ring $R$ with many ideals $\{I_1,I_2,\ldots,I_n\}$ but only a few, say $\{I_1~\text{and}I_2\}$, have the property that $J=Re=eR$ and the rest, say $\{I_3,\ldots,I_n\}$, are not idempotent ideals?  I am looking for examples even from non-Noetherian case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R$ is any nonfield integral domain, then every ideal except the trivial ones is not idempotent. Doesn’t that fit your description?

Comment: Thank you.  Are there cases for co-existence of both non-trivial idempotent ideals and non-trivial non-idempotent ideals  in the same ring $R$?

Comment: @mariam You mean, like in $R\times R$, where $R$ is a non field domain?  There are only four idempotent ideals.